# Download geo-referenced photos from ESRI collector app

Tags: arcgis-collector

I have ESRI Collector app on an iPad. I have used it to mark up a number of features on site, complete with photos and videos.

My end goal is a kmz of georeferenced features complete with photos in Google Earth (the videos I'll just have to provide a link or similar).

I am stuck at the first hurdle and cannot work out how to export the features with photos into either arcmap or Google Earth. I can export the collector feature class as a shapefile or various other formats but none have the photos linked as far as I can tell.

How can I accomplish this download of georeferenced photos?

Comment: You can download feature sevice with attacnments as file gdb. Either from my content or through rest, create replica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of getting to your attached photos is to:

1. Go to My Contents on ArcGIS online.
2. Go to the view item details section of your hosted feature layer.
3. You have Description, Access and use constraints and then Layers. Click on the tiny arrow next to your layer with the attachments and export to FGDB. This can take a few minutes.
4. Back in My Contents you will see a new item described as a File Geodatabase. Click on the tiny arrow and select download. You'll get some wacky name for it but that can be easily renamed in ArcCatalog.